# vue.js - set initial model value from .NET view model

Tags: .net, vue.js, asp.net-core

I have this line:

```
<label><input style="margin-top:0" type="checkbox" asp-for="Properties.IsThisChecked" v-model="isThisChecked" /> Is This Checked?</label>
<div v-show="isThisChecked">
<!-- other code...
```

It is bound to both the Vue JS model (isThisChecked) and to the .NET view model property (Propertied.IsThisChecked). I already know that v-model ignores all pre-set values in the HTML, and instead takes its initialized value. But I need the starting value from the .NET view model.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 1):

You serialize the model and initialize your Vue with that:

```
let data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
let vm = new Vue({
    ...
    data: data
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to serialize the whole model, that's fine: just serialize the parts you need. In some cases, serialization may not be necessary, at all. For example, if the property you want is already a primitive type like a string or int. Essentially:

```
data: {
    someString: "@Model.SomeString",
    someInt: @Model.SomeInt,
    someList: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SomeList)),
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. One issue I have with this is that it will serialize the WHOLE model, which is huge and mostly unnecessary. I only need a small handful of properties from the view model.